# How can I write a Regex expression like this

Tags: regex

How can I write a RegEx expression match the number begin with 890 or 1234 and its whole lengh is 10 if 890 or 11 if 1234
For example:
the input string : abc89093567892bcd
the result is :8909356789
the input string : abc123498912335bcd
the result is :12349891233

Comment: Please phrase this more precisely.

Comment: And an example input text and your regex and what you want to select

Comment: By definition any number which is 10 or 11 digits long will start with 4 digits.

Comment: I think you use the word 'digit' when you mean 'non-digit'. a/b/c would not be considered 'digits'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using perl or sed, you could try something like:

```
/\d{3,11}/
```

\d is for digit, and {3,11} means that a digit must appear between 3 and 11 times.